# Message filter using Approximate time policy. callback function called once

Tags: ros, message-filters, approximatetime, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to access images and ultrasound reading from my ardrone parrot. To get readings in synchronized way i tried using message filter with approximate time policy.

`image_transport::SubscriberFilter sub(it_,"/out_resize", 110);
message_filters::Subscriber<ardrone_autonomy::navdata_altitude> altitude_sub(nh,
"/ardrone/navdata_altitude", 100);
sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image,ardrone_autonomy::navdata_altitude> MySyncPolicy;
Synchronizer sync(MySyncPolicy(200),sub,altitude_sub);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&VideoSource::callback,this, _1, _2));`

Callback function

`void VideoSource::callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& img_msg,const ardrone_autonomy::navdata_altitude::ConstPtr &msg)
{
fprintf(stderr,"inside\n");
alti_raw=*msg;
img = *img_msg;
is_frame_available = true;
}`

This callback is only called once even though I am receiving continuous messages on both the topics. The difference between timestamps is around 100ms.

Can anyone tell me why this callback is getting called only once..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64610/message-filter-using-approximate-time-policy.-callback-function-called-once../) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-06-09**:
@sergey_alexandrov  Thanks a lot man..declaring sync in constructor was the problem..

**Comment by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) on 2013-06-10**:
You may close the question so as to remove it from the "Unanswered" list and improve the overall statistics :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although you did not paste the complete listing, it seems like the `sync` object is not a member field of your `VideoSource` class, but rather a local variable (in constructor I guess). If this is the case then `sync` is destructed as soon as the constructor is executed, which removes the callback.

---

Originally posted by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) with karma: 260 on 2013-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1